# How to connect via vb .net to ios APN

Tags: ios, vb.net, notifications, push, pkcs#12

I'm having some truble in connecting out of the box to the sandbox server of apple. I don't really know if it's just my programatically fault or if it's my certificate.

Lets have a look:

```
Using client As New TcpClient()
        client.Connect("gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com", 2195)
        Using networkStream As NetworkStream = client.GetStream()
            Console.WriteLine("Client connected.")

            Dim clientCertificate As New X509Certificate("certfile.p12", "PASS")
            Dim clientCertificateCollection As New X509CertificateCollection(New X509Certificate(0) {clientCertificate})

            ' Create an SSL stream that will close the client's stream.
            Dim sslStream As New SslStream(client.GetStream(), False, AddressOf ValidateServerCertificate, Nothing)

            Try
                sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient("gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com", clientCertificateCollection, SslProtocols.Default, False)
            Catch ex As AuthenticationException
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", ex.Message)
                If ex.InnerException IsNot Nothing Then
                    Console.WriteLine("Inner exception: {0}", ex.InnerException.Message)
                End If
                Console.WriteLine("Authentication failed - closing the connection.")
                client.Close()
                Return
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
```

I'm getting following error: "Failed in SSPI-Call".

Now my question, which certificate must I export in keychain? My private key, aps_provisioning, apple development cert or my developer cert?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I got it working! You have to create it like this:

openssl x509 -in aps_developer_identity.cer -inform der -out PushChatCert.pem

openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out PushChatKey.pem -in PushChatKey.p12

cat PushChatCert.pem PushChatKey.pem > ck.pem

Then trying to connect:

openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert PushChatCert.pem -key PushChatKey.pem

And for C# or in my case vb you must create a .p12 file with this console command:

openssl pkcs12 -export -out ck.p12 -inkey ck.pem -in ck.pem

That's it!

Comment: Daniel - can you contact me eljaywilson_at_gmail_dot_com?  I am starting on doing push notifications using IIS and VB.net and it sounds like you got a good handle on this.

Comment: @webprogrammer post here working code in vb.net

Comment: @Theorist that's working code up there, read it please. Also watch my own comment under the question. The problem was the Cert-Files. Please consider ther word "please" as I don't have to post working code for others...